# Find Replica Identity for a Postgres table

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

Is there a way to see what kind of replica identity a Postgres table has, whether using pgAdmin or through a query?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can query the [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) system catalog:

```
SELECT CASE relreplident
          WHEN 'd' THEN 'default'
          WHEN 'n' THEN 'nothing'
          WHEN 'f' THEN 'full'
          WHEN 'i' THEN 'index'
       END AS replica_identity
FROM pg_class
WHERE oid = 'mytablename'::regclass;
```

Comment: It's also useful to know all tables with no primary key if you use default logical replica identity - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29932/how-can-i-list-all-tables-without-a-primary-key#answer-29933

Comment: If you set the replica identity of a table to an index you could find the relevant index with `SELECT indexrelid::regclass FROM pg_index WHERE indrelid='mytablename'::regclass AND indisreplident;`

Answer (score 1):

Find replica identify for multiple tables. The query will list the tablename as its replica identity status.

```sql
SELECT oid::regclass,CASE relreplident
          WHEN 'd' THEN 'default'
          WHEN 'n' THEN 'nothing'
          WHEN 'f' THEN 'full'
          WHEN 'i' THEN 'index'
       END AS replica_identity
FROM pg_class
WHERE oid in ('public.testtable1'::regclass,'public.testtable1'::regclass);
```